# Css input HTML, why absolute position changing when updating width

Tags: html, css

Why position of the input element changging on `keyup`, in my `css` I already set the div to `position:absolute` and only change the `width` on the `keyup` function, I want only the `width` of the input that change not include the position

```js
$('.test').keydown(function(){
 var contents = $(this).val();
 var charlength = contents.length;
 newwidth =  charlength*9;
 $(this).css({width:newwidth});
});
```

```css
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
  #parent div {
      position: absolute;
      left: 5px;
      right: 5px;
    top:300px;
  }
    #parent div input {
        position: relative;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* IE */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Opera */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Internet Explorer */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
    <div class='yyy'><input class='test' type="text" value='jjjj'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `transform: rotate(...)` property by default rotates the element around its center. Changing the width of the element makes its center move, so the transformed element appears to change the position. To prevent it, change the `transform-origin` of the element, e.g. to its left top corner (`0 0`):

```js
$('.test').keydown(function(){
 var contents = $(this).val();
 var charlength = contents.length;
 newwidth =  charlength*9;
 $(this).css({width:newwidth});
});
```

```css
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
  #parent div {
      position: absolute;
      left: 5px;
      right: 5px;
    top:300px;
  }
    #parent div input {
        position: relative;
  /* and please use the standard CSS instead of old prefixed junk! */
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform-origin: 0 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
    <div class='yyy'><input class='test' type="text" value='jjjj'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Please use standard unprefixed CSS properties (`transform` etc.) and not their ancient experimental prefixed versions! Browsers that don't support the standard syntax are practically extinct for years. If you really need to, you can use automatic tools like Autoprefixer to generate only prefixes that your audience really needs.